# IF/OR AND formulas?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I need a formula that will read 2 possibilities in 2 different cells and output 1 of 3 possible outcomes in a third. 
So if the first column can be 'new' or 'used' and the second column can be 'yes' or 'no' the third column needs to have; a value of 10 IF 'new' and 'yes', 20 if 'used' and 'yes' and return a value of 0 if the second column is a 'no' regardless of the first. 
Can anyone help please!

Comment: Set up a look up table.

Comment: See [ask] and take the [tour]. Requests for complete solutions are not going to get much traction here. Show your research and and [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: If one of the two answers solved your problem the you should accept one of them using the check mark on the left... It is only polite after all - they did domething nice for you...

Answer (score 2):

```
=(B1="yes")*((A1="used")+1)*10
```

[image]

Comment: Now adding 1 to a False or True result - that is **neat**, learnt something today.. plus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the formula you will want to use for Column C:

```
=if(b2="no",0,if(a2="new",10,20))
```

[image: example]